# Is it possible to do linear regression on participants' level?

Tags: regression, lm

Each participant had 16 rating values, and there were two (say A and B) trial-wise parameters I could get based on our task. I want to see how A/B contribute to the rating for each subject.
Is there any appropriate way to compute that? I know individual data could be very noisy and the parameter estimate could be unreliable. But I still want to get some approximation.

My intuitive idea is that first build a regression model and get the standard regression coefficients (`betaA` and `betaB`) for each subject. Then compute the contribution of A as [`betaA^2/(betaA^2+betaB^2)`]. Does this make sense?

Comment: Participants are random effects, then you can get the random effect of each participant.